# ASP.NET: Insert Multiple Values from a Dropdownlist into Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I insert two different values into columns of a table in a database when both values come from the same DropDownList? For example one value is 'name' and the other is 'id'.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good database if you have to store both the look-up ID and it's name someplace else.  You might get more out of addressing the design of your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your situation.
the 'name' value is the `DataTextField` in the `dropDown`,
and the 'id' value is the `DataValueField` in the dropDown.
so,

If it's realy like that, it simple to do it, you have to take the:
`DropDownList1.Items[ DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].Text` - this is the 'name' value, and the:   `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` - this is the 'id' value.