# ASP.NET:Get data into Radiobuttonlist from database

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert data into radiobuttonlist from the database. but i get this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

even though i have set the datatype of the field as VARCHAR(MAX). and the data in that field is a simple 4 letter word..say 'john'.

my code for inserting data is like this.:

RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Text = obj.dr["op1"].ToString();

RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Text = obj.dr["op2"].ToString();

RadioButtonList1.Items[2].Text = obj.dr["op3"].ToString();

RadioButtonList1.Items[3].Text = obj.dr["op4"].ToString();

Comment: Please post all relevant code

Comment: Are the radiobuttonlist items equal to the number of DB field items ? What are _obj_ and _dr_ ?

Comment: You also need to mark your answers when they work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805522/asp-net-values-of-a-dropdownlist-into-database

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to bind a list to a DataSet. The example calls a stored proceedure:

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/10/12/Bind-CheckBoxList-to-DataSet.aspx